# How to achieve a sheet of paper unfolding from the center in XNA 2D?

Tags: xna, 2d

I need to create an effect like a folded sheet of paper unfolding.

I was thinking about transforming an image so it "scales" from the center to the borders by cutting the image in half and scaling both parts to create this effect.

Is there a better way?

Comment: What do you want it to look like?  Paper unfolding in 2d could literally look like a rectangle growing wider.

Comment: That is it, but for that i would need it to grown from the center to the borders. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to accomplish something like this:

[image]

You can do this pretty easily.  If you create 3 different gameobjects, each with a SpriteRenderer:

[image]

The Gameobject on the left, has a blank image with a pivot set to TopLeft.  The Gameobject on the right, has the same image, however, the pivot is set to the TopRight.

Re-position these gameobjects, so that they are over top the Center object:

[image]

Then all you have to do is attach a script like this to both Blue gameobjects:

```
bool Opening = true;

void Update () {
    if (Opening) {
        transform.localScale = new Vector2 (transform.localScale.x - (0.5f * Time.deltaTime), transform.localScale.y);
        if (transform.localScale.x < -0.5f) {
            transform.localScale = new Vector2 (-0.5f, transform.localScale.y);
            Opening = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged with XNA, so a very Unity-specific answer might not be the one the asker is looking for.

Comment: Yeah, ffs, I do this all the time.  Although, this technique could be carried over to XNA using similar concepts.  Its not like this is very complicated stuff.

Comment: That would not do. I was talking about scalling because I do need to show the whole image growing. When paper unfolds, you can see the whole image, but distorted. Your example looks more of an unveil effect. I will try and get an image example. More like this image : http://cdn.freshome.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Funny-foldout-cards-by-Etsy-Shop-FINCHandHare-.jpg
Please, dont mind the message...its no me tryinh to be funny, its just the first one i found :/

Comment: Then I think the only way is going to be folding a mesh in 3d space.  Otherwise, you are going be doing a heck of a lot of work trying to reproduce this in 2d (as far as I can tell anyways)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433989.aspx) overload of the `SpriteBatch.Draw()` method. What you want to do is have the `origin` argument be a `Vector2` with its x-coordinate set to half the width of your final image (and whichever y-coordinate you feel is appropriate), and increase the `scale` argument from `(0,1)` to `(1,1)` over the course of time it takes to "unfold" the paper.

Since unfolding paper occurs in 3D, and moves (roughly) like the arc of a circle, what you might consider doing is setting the x-coordinate of `scale` use cosine to regulate its movement. Your code should end up looking something like this:

```
// In your initialization code:
Vector2 origin = new Vector2(paperObject.Width/2f, 0);
// In your Update():
unfoldTimer += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
paperScale = new Vector2(Math.Cos(unfoldTimer/UnfoldTime * Math.PI * 0.5d), 1);
```

Note that this is only an approximation of what unfolding would look like, and it's probably the closest you're going to get by just scaling.